# Bug in jQuery resizable

Tags: jquery, resizable, simulate

I'm experiencing a bug in jQuery UI's Resizable trying to use it with jQuery UI's dialog, where it's not respecting the `containment` option when given a selector or a DOM element, and generally behaving very weirdly on resize.

I'm basically doing this:

```
dialog = $('<div>...</div>').dialog(options)
dialog.parent().draggable(options).resizable(options)
```

So I need another way to do containment for resizing.

Is there a way I can simulate containment, maybe via the `resize` callback of the `resizable` call? Where I could maybe check if the `div` would be too big on resize, and force it to an acceptable size?

Comment: Post your code and the behavior also; maybe we can figure out why it's giving you unexpected results.

Comment: @JonathanM I'm working on a minimal sample that reproduces the problem, but my web page was already really big and it'll take a while to figure out what environment produces the bad behaviour. In the mean time, do you know a direct answer to the  question?

Comment: @JonathanM I added some info, see if that helps at all, still working on an example...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can't just call`.draggable()` on the dialog object itself.

It also doesn't help the jQueryUI reparents every dialog element into the `<body>` tag.

Try this:

```
// create the dialog
var w = $('<div>');
...
$(w).dialog(dlg_options);

// reparent the dialog, and reset the draggable options
var dlg = $(w).data('dialog').uiDialog;
$(dlg).appendTo(real_parent);
$(dlg).draggable(drag_options);
```

Note that this use of hidden jQueryUI internals (`.uiDialog`) *may* break in future versions.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left out the `resizable(options)` call, which is where the trouble is, not with `draggable`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie same applies - use `$(dlg).resizable()` using the `.uiDialog` data member as above.

Comment: or possibly `$(dlg).data().resizable`

Comment: No, I still get the same result. The dialog box itself only resizes up and down, but the div inside it resizes horizontally, and even it doesn't respect the containment div.

Comment: @SethCarnegie you need to provide an example then.